# What directories should be included to MANUALLY compile source with cl.exe on Windows?

Tags: windows, cl.exe

How can I set up -I cl.exe arguments in order to make my primitive .cpp file to compile? I want this to be done neither with calling Developer Command Prompt nor with vsvars32.bat file or any other .bat file which will set up all environment variables for me.

I need to know what paths to point in my -I options.

My .cpp file does not contain something special. It depends only on usual STL/system files. Here is what is included.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>
```

Comment: You could just look at what vcvars32.bat does... In general, the CRT headers are in `/VC/include`, the lib files are in `/lib`. Of course, you'll need to get the right ones for your processor architecture. Why don't you want to use vsvars32.bat, again?

Comment: Read rsvars32.bat to see what environmental variables it sets up. You'll either have to set them up yourself, or provide the information those vars contain on the command line to cl.exe. You can find the swtiches and options for cl.exe by typing `cl.exe /?` from a command prompt. If you're dead set on doing all of the hard stuff yourself that the batch file does for you easily, have fun. You're not going to enjoy the ride.

Comment: Just let the IDE tell you this, it is visual.  Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories setting.  Click on the dropdown button to see actual values.  Intentionally avoiding vcvars32, well, there are other ways to flog yourself that hurt more.

Comment: Acually I am ok with compiling my source with a help of vcvars32.bat. But I am also trying to make YouCompleteMe plugin for Vim editor work. It introduces live code analysis with clang. YouCompleteMe needs -I settings for my compiler. They are put in ycm_extra_conf.py file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the long story short here is my command for cmd.exe. Note I didn't run any .bat files to setup any variables.

```
cl.exe -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\lib\um\x86" 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" 
A.cpp /EHsc
/link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib"   
/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib" 
/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86" 
/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86"
```

I followed Hans Passant advice to look in Visual Studio VC++ Directories. Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories setting. Alternatively one can run vcvars32.bat and then echo %INCLUDE% and %LIB% environment variables.

Include directories for cl.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt
```

Library directories for linker:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\Lib\um\x86
```

As you can see I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and that are the things for my case.